# How do I align words in different rows to be like a table

Tags: php

I have a php script that saves 3 words to a text file every time it is run, how do I align those words to always be at a certain point in the line in different rows to be like a table so for example the first word should always be at the beginning of the line, the second word should be 15 columns into the line, the third word should be 30 columns into the line.

I have researched for a long time how to do this and I couldn't find an answer that works for me.

Here is my code to save 3 variables and one word to a file

```
$example1 = "example1"
$example2 = "example2"
$example3 = "example3"

$myfile = fopen("example.txt", "a");
$txt =  "\n$example1 $example2 word $example3";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

each time I run this php my variables wont necessarily be the same length (they will never be longer than 15 characters, so I think that is a good distance between each column), so they could look like this...

```
$example1 = "example123"
$example2 = "example34"
$example3 = "exam"
```

Currently my results in the text file look like this after I run it twice with those two examples

```
example1 example2 word example3
example123 example34 word exam
```

but I want it to look like this

```
example1       example2       word example3
example123     example34      word exam
```

Comment: Save them to an HTML document with a styled `<table>`element, or as a CSV document?

Comment: http://www.djswebdesign.com/creating-a-space-delimited-text-file/

Comment: @moonwave99 how would I do that if I if I want the script to add to the table on a regular basis?

Comment: To solve the immediate question, you can use tabs: \t

Comment: @imvain2 that will just separate them, I am trying to make them in a neat column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pad each the first two strings to 15 characters with `str_pad` before writing the line to the file.

```
$example1 = str_pad($example1, 15);
$example2 = str_pad($example2, 15);

$myfile = fopen("example.txt", "a");
$txt =  "\n$example1 $example2 word $example3";

fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

`str_pad` will pad the string with spaces on the right by default.

---

Opinionated section:
*If this is a data file that you'll read at some other point in your program*, I'd really recommend using a delimited format like CSV rather than a fixed width format like this. It's simpler to write code to read a format like that, and if the main point of the file is to store data that will be read by a program, I think that's more important than human readability.

Answer (score 0):

interesting question, then if some small variation with long words bothers you, it confirms to read the whole file and define the longest talk, otherwise you should do the following:

```
$example1 = "example1"
$example2 = "example2"
$example3 = "example3"

$myfile = fopen("example.txt", "a");
$txt =  "\n$example1\t$example2\tword $example3";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

note the \t between the words, this prints the tab character

I repeat, for the words that year different characters of difference this is possible only through the reading of the file and successively determine the longest spoken word contained. once found you need to add as many tabs as are needed to move to the next indentation tab